# CKeditor integration in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, ckeditor

I have replaced textarea's with ckeditor in my webapp which is being built on struts2and hibernate, but when i try to save the data in *mysqldb* it throws an error

the ckeditordata is being stored as a string

```
 1. `class student {    String studentDesc; }`
```

hibernate mapping

```
    <property name="studentDesc" type="java.lang.String">
                <column name="STUDENTDESC" /> </property>
```

when i try to save the editor data without any images it is getting saved but when i try to save with images it is throwing  the below error

```
Unable to show problem report:
freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: Method public
java.lang.String
org.hibernate.exception.NestableRuntimeException.getMessage(int) threw
an exception when invoked on
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert:
[com.project.sourc......
```

Can some one help on this?

Comment: please show the complete call stack

Comment: sorry for the late response. The issue got resolved now.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Issue got resolved ...

I have changed the type from "java.lang.String" to "text" in the hibernate mapping file and the issue got resolved.

Earlier when it was String, the field in database was of VARCHAR(255) and the application was trying to insert large data which was throwing an exception. Now after changing it to text the issue got resolved.